# AWS Glue - Data is not inserting into desired destination

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a Glue job for inserting data into S3 location. I wanted to insert the data into a specific CSV file in my folder, but the glue job is creating new destination file in each run. Can you please guide me what is wrong in this code snippet?

```
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource_lk, mappings = [("row_id", "bigint", "row_id", "bigint"), ("Quantity", "long", "Quantity", "long"),("Category", "string", "Category", "string") ], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")

selectfields2 = SelectFields.apply(frame = applymapping1, paths = ["row_id", "Quantity", "Category"], transformation_ctx = "selectfields2")

resolvechoice3 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = selectfields2, choice = "MATCH_CATALOG", database = "mydb", table_name = "order_summary_csv", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice3")

datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(frame = resolvechoice3, database = "mydb", table_name = "order_summary_csv", transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
job.commit()
```

I have a CSV file(order_summary.csv) in a particular S3 folder, but instead of inserting records into it, glue is creating new folder called  order_summary.csv and inserting file with some random names inside of this folder.

Comment: That is the way how spark saves the files. Spark will not save a file but the files inside a folder that is specified by you.

Comment: I guess you are looking for something like a merge in a RDBMS table. Spark doesn't work that way as pointed by @Lamanus

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I have 2 more doubts,1)  what is the use 'ResolveChoice' in this code? is it mandatory? 2) Why are we mentioning 'table_name = "order_summary_csv"' in the last line of the code if Spark is going to save files seperately in its own way?